# diff shows a file that does not exist

Tags: filenames, diff

I created a backup on an external hard disc. Then I created another backup and copied all files to another external hard disc. I wanted to check with `diff` if everything was copied:

```
user@user:/media/user$ diff -r backup backup1
Nur in backup1/home/user: file.xls.
Nur in backup1/home/user: file.zip.
```

("nur" is German for "only".)

The diff shows two files that are not existing:

```
user@user:/media/user$ file backup1/home/user/file.xls.
backup1/home/user/file.xls.: cannot open backup1/home/user/file.xls. (No such file or directory)
user@user:/media/user$ file backup1/home/user/file.zip.
backup1/home/user/file.zip.: cannot open backup1/home/user/file.zip. (No such file or directory)
```

How does it come that diff shows these two files, and how can I fix the output of diff?
The filesystem is LUKS on both external hard drives.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The output of `diff -r` with a German locale adds a `.` to the file.
Files `backup1/home/user/file.xls` and `backup1/home/user/file.zip` should exist.

Example:

```
$ mkdir dir1 dir2
$ touch dir1/foo
$ LANG=de_DE.UTF8 diff -r dir1 dir2
Nur in dir1: foo.
$ diff -r dir1 dir2
Only in dir1: foo
```

Comment: Oh i did not thought about that because i got many files with an ending dot...
Thank you!

Comment: What a weird feature!  Great discovery!

Comment: You should submit a bug report about this. Looking through the  `po` directory of `diffutils`, only the [DE translation](https://github.com/Distrotech/diffutils/blob/9e70e1ce7aaeff0f9c428d1abc9821589ea054f1/po/de.po#L1128) does append a period to the filename. All european languages end sentences with a period, there's nothing that stringently German about it. In this case, they could just get rid of it like everybody else ;-)

Comment: I will do later. Some scripts could break with this dot and German locale. I was used to English locale, too.

Comment: I filled a bug but don't know if this is the right place. Bug number 1 seems not right ;)
https://github.com/Distrotech/diffutils/issues/1
If there is a better place please tell me.